# Is there a specific data type for counting bit shifts?

Tags: c

Let's say I want to bit shift a uint128_t value and I want to keep track how many times I performed this operation.
Which type of counter should I use? Is there a custom data type to support that?
Or should I just use a char data type as it's max size is 128?

The following is just an example. count_bits is the important variable here.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long long count_bits(long long n)
  {
  uint8_t count_bits;
  
  count_bits = 0;
  while (n)
    {
    n >>= 1;
    count_bits++;
  }
  return (count_bits);
}
int main()
{
    printf("%lld", count_bits(LLONG_MAX));
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Using bit-shifting alone it is impossible to calculate the "maximum value" of any type, as the maximum value requires all bits to be set (except for signed types where the MSB is left unset)...

Comment: Signed char can (usually) fit up to `127`. Are you trying to save memory or something? Any integer type except `signed char` can count up to `128`

Comment: There's no specific datatype for this. But `uint8_t` can hold up to 255, which should be plenty.

Comment: If you want the maximum `uint128_t`, just use `(uint128_t)-1`

Comment: @dbush He's not asking how to get the maximum `uint128_t`, he's asking what datatype should be in a shift amount variable that can shift the maximum amount.

Comment: Du you want the same bits to be set in the result as in the original variable, only bitshifted left so the msb is set?

Comment: So many comments :). I'm not sure how an example would help, but for some reason I thought that unit8_t had 8 bytes instead of bits. Furthermore, @Barmar is right that I only care about a variable type that is suitable for counting the shift operations. I also thought of char, but that seemed quite inappropriate for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not trying to save memory, but I'm seeking conventions @EugeneSh.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not sure what a msb is, and I'm not trying to set the same bits in the original value

Comment: @SaladinAfoh No specific convention. Some might argue, that any iteration should be done with `size_t` type, but it is really not necessary here.

Comment: @SaladinAfoh msb or MSb = most significant bit. Ok, so for the input `0xEF` what is the expected result? Does the expected result even depend on the input value?

Comment: Re “I'm not sure how an example would help”: Your question is unclear, and there are multiple interpretations of the words in it. Giving an example rules out all interpretations that are not consistent with the example. In any case, regardless of whether you are or are not sure how an example could help, provide one, and edit the question to clarify it. If you do not, your question is likely to be voted closed soon.

Comment: @TedLyngmo give me a moment to get the code to work and I'll share it

Comment: @EricPostpischil I will provide one shortly

Comment: Problems with the question as phrased: (a) “bit shift a uint128_t value to its maximum value”: A value is a value; if it is shifted, it is no longer that value. So it is nonsensical to ask to shift a value to its maximum value. Shifting 3 two bits to make 12 gives 12, not the maximum value of 3, which is 3. (b) Maybe the question asks for some sort of bit-shifting or other manipulation of values in the `uint128_t` type to produce the maximum value representable in that type. However, this is simply `(uint128_t) -1`, so it is unclear why there is any request for bit-shifting.

Comment: (c) Another interpretation is that, given some `uint128_t`, we want to shift it so that its most significant bit (its leading 1 bit) is in the most significant position of the `uint128_t`. E.g., if the binary for the value is 1, we want to shift it 127 positions to make it 1 followed by 127 0s, or, if the value is 101, we want to shift it 125 positions to make it 101 followed by 125 0s.

Comment: (d) A fourth interpretation is that give some value, say 1011, we want to shift it by some amount that gives the largest result of any possible shift. For example, shifting 1011 by 124 positions would give 1011 followed by 124 0s, but shifting it 126 positions would give 11 followed by 126 0s, which is larger.

Comment: As we can see, there are multiple interpretations of this vague phrasing. The question cries out for clarification.

Comment: @EricPostpischil @ I just added some example code. I hope this will help you understand what I meant.

Comment: @SaladinAfoh You say _" to the left"_ but you shift to the right.

Comment: I have also rephrased to question for more clarity. @EricPostpischil Thanks for pointing out the vagueness. The maximum value had nothing to do with the question so I can see how that confuses a lot of people.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I removed the direction

Comment: Unless you are going to shift more than 255 bits, you can simply use an `unsigned char`. You can also use an `int`, and it will not likely make any difference to performance in speed or memory size unless you have a lot of them.

Comment: unless you care about space, use `int`

Comment: I still hope that someone can give me a definitive answer on this question.

Comment: What more do you want than `unsigned char` suffices unless you are going to shift more than 255 bits, and that you can use `int` if you want (it was designed to be C’s general-purpose integer type? This choice is not going to make any noticeable difference in a program except with special circumstances such as using a great many of such counters at the same time or in a data structure or perhaps some esoteric high-performance situation, and there is basis for neither of those in the question. Just use whichever you prefer, `unsigned char` or `int`, and be done with it.

Comment: Some char implementations (the signed ones) have a maximum value of 127, not 128. Sounds like nitpicking but sometimes the difference between a working program and a crash is only 1 ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: No `char` implementation has a maximum of 128 unless somebody implemented a `char` with more than eight bits and made all values above 128 trap values. C’s integer types must have binary representations, so the maximum values are 127, 255, 511, and so on, except for values excluded because they are used for traps.

Comment: If you want to count something, and unless you have special requirements, you should use a counter of type `int`.   *If* you have special requirements, you *may* find that, after careful analysis, a different (perhaps a smaller) type is appropriate, and will work.  But I assert that you have no special requirements, and I furthermore assert that even if there were some compelling argument why you might maybe want to use a smaller type, *the preceding 1000+ words worth of discussion **prove** that the arguments are too complicated for the change to be worth it*.  Just use `int`.

Comment: Your `count_bits()` function should return `int`, as well.  It's shown as returning `long long`, which is meaningless (although, yes, it will work).

Comment: @SteveSummit Prove is a strong word. If you have any resources that back the discussion. I'm eager to take a look!

Comment: @SaladinAfoh What I meant was, if you use type `int`, it will be fine, no one will question it.  If you use something other than type `int`, you may have to justify it, *and* the time spent justifying it had better be less than the time saved due to the superiority of that other type, versus type `int`.  My assertion (not quite a proof, but close) is that the superiority of that other type is 0, while the time spent justifying it is not only nonzero, it's been shown ("1000+ words") to be significantly nonzero. So I still don't see how using anything other than `int` could ever be justified.

Comment: Here's a closely-related problem.  It's not uncommon to have an array of size 256 to initialize.  And it's extremely, seductively tempting to try to "optimize" the initialization loop by using something like`for(uint8_t i=0; i<256; i++) a[i] = i;`  Probably every C programmer has written that code at least once — I know I have.  But it *does not work*, and it is not necessarily easy to see why it does not work — I remember spending several hours on it the first time I had the problem.  So the cost is highly negative, while the benefit is, again, 0.  The moral of the story is: just use `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific reason to use a larger or smaller type, which doesn't seem to be the case here, it's typically best to just use `int`.

So `count_bits` should have type `int` and `count_bits` should return type `int`.